# AWS s3 ls command is returning an extra row

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, ls

When I do `aws s3 ls s3://mybucket/folder`, I'm getting an extra row. I'm expecting 6 rows, but am getting back 7. Output looks like:

```
2015-10-13 15:10:10  0    folder/
2015-10-13 15:10:10  12   folder/test1.txt
2015-10-13 15:10:10  123  folder/test2.txt
2015-10-13 15:10:10  53   folder/test3.txt
2015-10-13 15:10:10  12   folder/test4.txt
2015-10-13 15:10:10  42   folder/test5.txt
2015-10-13 15:10:10  12   folder/test6.txt
```

S3 doesn't show 7 items, it just shows 6. This was running perfectly fine an hour ago but suddenly started showing that first item just now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often, software that manipulates Amazon S3 objects will create this mysterious zero-length object as a placeholder for a "folder", because Amazon S3 does not support folders in the normal sense.

You might be able to delete it with `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/folder/`. This will not delete the contents of the folder (since folders don't exist!).

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing `aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/folder/t` and got the wanted results. Not what I wanted to do since it's assuming a few things, but it'll do for now

Comment: Very good to know! I suppose that if one wants to iterate over the files in an S3 bucket, then this zero-length file has to be filtered out in case it is present.